# Avoid Cartesian Product in SQL when using Where in clause

Tags: sql, cartesian-product, where-in

My query goes below

```
 select a.col1,a.col2,b.col1,b.col2 from table1 a, table2 b
 where a.col3=value and b.col2 in (select col from table1 where col3=val)
```

This is giving be repeated values
Eg.

Result obtained

```
-----------------------
S.No| Name| Value| Code
------------------------
1| Delhi| capital| 100
------------------------
2 |Mumbai| city | 101
------------------------
1 |Delhi| city| 101
------------------------
2 |Mumbai| capital |100
------------------------
```

Expected Result

```
 -----------------------
S.No| Name| Value| Code
------------------------
1 |Delhi| capital |100
----------------------
2 |Mumbai| city |101
----------------------
```

I tried Group by it is not working. How could this be solved?

Sample Data

Table 1

```
------------------------
S.NO| Name |Type |Value
```

---

```
1| Delhi |BIGCITY| Capital
-------------------------
2| Mumbai| BIGCITY| City
------------------------
```

Table 2

```
---------------
Value |Code
---------------  
Capital |100 
---------------
City |101
--------------
```

```
  select a.sno,a.name,b.value,b.code from table1 a, table2 b
    where a.type=BIGCITY and b.col2 in (select value from table1 where col3=BIGCITY)
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data i.e. the data in the table you are trying to query?

Comment: Please describe what you actually want to achieve here.From the query alone, it's not quite clear. Also, please provide the input tables so that the example can be reproduced.

Comment: If you used a "modern"-style join (they've only been a standard part of SQL for a quarter of a century) and expressed an actual *join condition* between tables `a` and `b`, you wouldn't have a cartesian join.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My thought exactly, but the question is in too broken of a state to really attempt a meaningful query.

Comment: For future questions, you might want to read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank You!

Comment: Update your tables and label each column in a readable way.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think the join cannot be used for my case. If so can you rewrite and show can that can be done? Because i just take the value from the other table for using in "where condition"

Comment: So is this not `from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.value = b.value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this basic join query:

```
SELECT a.sno,
       a.name,
       COALESCE(b.value, 'NA') AS value,
       COALESCE(b.code, 'NA') AS code
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
    ON a.value = b.value
WHERE a.type = 'BIGCITY'
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: What about the Where a.type="BIGCITY"? that condition is not met

Comment: That coalesce part is not working , if i remove that i get null result for b.value and b.code

Comment: My query works as expected using the data you provided, q.v. the Fiddle I gave you.  If it is not "working" then your data must be the reason.

Comment: without the where condition its working fine,  but when i introduce where condition the value from table2 is displayed as NULL or NA,NA(if i use coalesce)

Comment: As I already have said, your data has a problem.  Using the data you provided, my query works, see the Fiddle.